# How to stop Silverstripe SearchContext from throwing Version Table_Live error

Tags: search, silverstripe

Consider the following Silverstripe page class

```
<?php

class Page extends SiteTree{

static $has_many = array('OtherDataObjects' => 'DataObjectClass');

public function getSearchContext() {

    $fields = new FieldSet(

        new TextField('Title', 'Tour'),
        new DropdownField('OtherDataObjects', 'Other Data Object', array('data', 'value')
    );

    $filters = array(
      'Title' => new PartialMatchFilter('Title'),
      'OtherDataObjects' => new PartialMatchFilter('OtherDataObjects.Title')
    );
    return new SearchContext(
      'Page', 
      $fields, 
      $filters
   );
  }
}
```

Adding this search form to a front-end form and posting a search form always results in a [User Error] with a SQL error containing something like this at the end.

```
AND ("DataObjectClass_Live"."DataObjectClass_Live" LIKE 'title') ORDER BY "Sort" LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0 Table 'database DataObjectClass_Live' doesn't exist
```

My searchcontext search throws up an error each time I try to run a search on a has_many relationship. The versioned extension seems to be the culprit because it adds _live to all tables regardless whether the baseclass has the versioned extension or not I get the same error in SilverStripe versions 2.4.x and the latest 3.0.x versions.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: The Versioned sitetree extension adds _live to all the search queries and thats why it throws up the table does not exits error. Versioned need to be aware to not prepend _live to sql queries if the dataobject does not have the versioned extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try using an sqlQuery. something like

```
function SearchResults() {
  $select = array('*');
  $from = array('OtherDataObjects');
  $where = array('OtherDataObjects:PartialMatch' => '%' . $data['Title'] . '%');
  $sqlQuery = new SQLQuery($select, $from, $where);
  $results = $sqlQuery->execute();
  return $results;
}
```

`$data['Title']` is to be the value from the search textbox

partial match reference: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel

sql query reference: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/sqlquery

Comment: Thanks @Gavin. I ended up a custom SQLQuery to do the searches and it works perfectly. Thanks for the tip